# filling a combobox with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to fill a combobox but every time i add a new item in my database my combobox shows duplicate values here is my code:

```
 var items = "";
 $.post("ProductFail.aspx?cmd=fill", function (d) {

    var lst = eval("(" + d + ")");
    alert(lst);

    for (var i = 0; i < lst.length; i++) {
        items += "<option value='#PID#'>#PNAME#</option>";
        items = items.replace("#PID#", lst[i].P_Number);
        items = items.replace("#PNAME#", lst[i].P_Name);
        $(".sel").append(items);
    }

 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since items is a single combo box, you don't need to do a += since you're already appending it at the end of ".sel".

```
for (var i = 0; i < lst.length; i++) {
    items = "<option value='#PID#'>#PNAME#</option>";
    items = items.replace("#PID#", lst[i].P_Number);
    items = items.replace("#PNAME#", lst[i].P_Name);
    $(".sel").append(items);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is that you are doing += as well as appending. We can even simplify the code as below.

```
for (var i = 0; i < lst.length; i++) {
    $(".sel").append("<option value='"+lst[i].P_Number+"'>"+lst[i].P_Name+"</option>");
}
```